# Display Image's on same page from different folder using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

This code I get by search..

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Get url for address bar</title>
<script>
    function display(folder,img_name) 
    {
        var src = "http://localhost/UPLOADER/images/"+folder+"/"+img_name;
        show_image("http://localhost/UPLOADER/images/"+folder+"/"+img_name, 276,110, "Img");
    }


    function show_image(src, width, height, alt) 
    {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = src;
        img.width = width;
        img.height = height;
        img.alt = alt;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="image" value="" style="margin-top: 4px;" placeholder="Image_name" />
<button onclick="display('a','access')">DISPLAY IMAGE</button>

</body>
</html>
```

This code I take from site [for jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/eEtEU/1/) it worls well but I think I done some mistake in my code its not easy to grab the error as it display. undefined image and function display.

I want to add this for dynamic selection of image

```
<?php
     $img_name=$_POST['image'];
     $folder = substr($img_name, 0, 1);
?>
<button onclick="display('$folder','$img_name')">DISPLAY IMAGE</button>
```

for extension I use .htaccess `Options +MultiViews`
thanks

Comment: The first error: you are calling `DISPLAY` javascript function in php. That's not possible.

Comment: Ya that's I know But these are few changes done by me If you can Make this code error free and generate the result

Comment: What are you entering into the `image` field on screen?

Comment: I am entering the name of image without extension.

Comment: I m showing full code even then I m not getting the answer I want..

Comment: I just edited the code it will help for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok there are many many solutions to this problem, changing it to an ajax call to the php page to get the image/images would be one, a very simple solution would be this...

```
<?php
$image = (isset($_REQUEST['image'])) ? $_REQUEST['image'] : false;
$folder = ($image) ? substr($image, 0, 1) : false;
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Get url for address bar</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var image = '<?php echo ($image) ? $image : "false"; ?>';
    var folder = '<?php echo ($folder) ? $folder : "false"; ?>';
    var extension = '.jpg';
    function DISPLAY(folder,img_name, imgExt) {
        var finalExt = (typeof imgExt != 'undefined') ? imgExt : extension;
        if(img_name != 'false' && folder != 'false') {
            show_image("http://localhost/UPLOADER/images/"+folder+"/"+img_name+finalExt, 276,110, "Img");
        } else {
            console.log("looks like something was undefined, here's the values:");
            console.log(folder);
            console.log(img_name);
    } 
    }


    function show_image(src, width, height, alt) 
    {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = src;
        img.width = width;
        img.height = height;
        img.alt = alt;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
//if using jquery
$(document).ready(function() {
    //you could also add logic here to see if values are not 'false' and run function
    DISPLAY(folder, image);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="image" value="" style="margin-top: 4px;" placeholder="Image_name" />
<button>DISPLAY IMAGE</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Updated the code and tested on my localhost, it is working great. the image was loaded from localhost/UPLOADER/images/s/sexy the image was called sexy.jpg. and worked great, try it out ant let me know